# How to insert characters by pressing ALT + # (numpad)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

How to enable those function (alt + number) on my elementary OS? I can't insert tilde and "ñ" letter because I don't have those buttons and also can't use the alt + number. Someone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: This is great! thanks for the tip. Is there any way to make the KB behave exactly like it does in OSX? This works of course, but really slows down my typing in German.

Comment: useful table
http://web.archive.org/web/20140215122421/http://www.hermit.org/Linux/ComposeKeys.html

Comment: Is there any way to have those letters just pressing compose instead of compose and '? In my language those letters are used really often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In elementary OS 0.4 (Loki), the way to set the compose key is:

1. Open *Systems Settings*
2. Select *Keyboard*
3. Select *Layout*
4. Select which key you want to use as your *Compose key*

Answer (score 5):

Often this is easier with the [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key). With the compose key configured you use key combos to produce special characters. For example:

- For ë: <kbd>Compose</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>
- For ẽ: <kbd>Compose</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>
- For ô: <kbd>Compose</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>
- For á: <kbd>Compose</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

Note that you do not have to hold down the compose key; just press each key in order.

**To set the compose key**

1. Open "System Settings"
2. Select "Keyboard"
3. Select "Options".
4. In the left pane, select "Compose Key Position"
5. In the right pane, choose a key to act as <kbd>Compose</kbd>

---

Original answer from [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-accentuated-characters-like-%C3%AB)

Comment: Do you Windows key

Answer (score 3):

The feature that you mention is typical of Windows systems to write ASCII characters. The *nix OS's, like *elementaryOS*, don't use ASCII code. But you can use **UNICODE**, which it's more extensive than ASCII.

To type an unicode character you must use `Ctrl+Shift` followed by the code you can find at:

[List of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

To write them:

1. Make sure you don't have `Caps Lock` on.
2. Hold `Ctrl` and `Shift` keys meanwhile type `U`. Now you can see an underline U.
3. Release the keys `Ctrl` and `Shift`, and type the *Unicode* number.
4. Finally, hit `Enter`.

For example, to write the "Ñ" character, you must use the combination:

```
ctrl + shift + u + 00D1 + enter
```

**Scratch-text-editor issue:**

When you use this trick in Scratch, you can't see the underline U, but it works also.