# I have my password with an accent and i can't put them

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to know how to put an accent in Elementary OS 
I have a QWERTY keyboard in spanish, please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with unicode:

Pressing first Shift+Ctrl+U

Á
U+00C1
É
U+00C9
Í
U+00CD
Ó
U+00D3
Ú
U+00DA
á
U+00E1
é
U+00E9
í
U+00ED
ó
U+00F3
ú
U+00FA

More help:
http://www.ltool.net/characters_to_unicode_charts_in_spanish.php?unicode=1&nowpage=2

There os also another related question that can help you:

[How to insert characters by pressing ALT + # (numpad)?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4961/how-to-insert-characters-by-pressing-alt-numpad)

I hope it works but haven't tried myself in a password field.